# CSS margin strange behavior, why?

Tags: css, margins

Having the HTML below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <div style="width:400px;height:200px;background-color:Gray;margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
    <div style="width:400px;height:200px;background-color:Green;margin-top:10px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

the space between those two DIVs is only 10 pixels.

Why? Explain please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That behavior is called [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). The margin values are not added but the higher value is used:

> Vertical margins may collapse between certain boxes:
>
> - Two or more adjoining vertical margins of block boxes in the normal flow collapse. The resulting margin width is the maximum of the adjoining margin widths. […]
> - […]

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this ?
I don't like this behavior.

Comment: Why don’t you increase the values to 20px?

Comment: I won't increase the value to 20px because I will use margin in other contexts, I will have ASP .NET controls placed randomly at runtime on different spaces

Comment: This is not 'strange' behavior. It *is* how it is supposed to work.

Comment: You might be able to prevent the behaviour by using "clear:both" on the elements. I haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good [explanation of margin collapsing](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/?p=194). Basically, it seems that all adjacent margins will collapse into each other, per the CSS specification and against all common sense.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have the desired effect you can use "padding" instead, margins always collapse

Comment: padding isn't good for my purpose because I use the background-color CSS property

Comment: I think border is the right solution for this, but again, this is strange